# Pandas GroupBy and then choose one result using if or max

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of ids, states, places, types and populations:

| id | state | place | type | population |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | ontario | toronto | Place | 5429524.0 |
| A | ontario | ottawa | Capital | 989567.0 |
| B | saskatchewan | saskatoon | Place | 246376.0 |
| B | saskatchewan | regina | Place | 215106.0 |
| B | saskatchewan | moose jaw | Place | 33890.0 |

I groupby to get all states with the same ID:

```
grouped_df = locations_df.groupby(["id", "state"])
```

I then need to either get the row that has ['type']== 'Capital' OR if that doesn't exist in that group, then choose the row with the highest population. e.g.

| id | state | place | type | population |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | ontario | ottawa | Capital | 989567.0 |
| B | saskatchewan | saskatoon | Place | 246376.0 |

I can get these individually using:

```
locations_df.groupby(["id", "state"]).population.idxmax()

locations_df.groupby(["id", "state"]).filter(lambda x: (x['type']== 'Capital').any())
```

Is there a way to combine this into one call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort values by `type` and `population`:

- `type` by ascending order because 'C' is before 'P'
- `population` by descending order to have highest values at top

Then group by `id` and `state` columns and finally take the first value of each group:

```
out = df.sort_values(['type', 'population'], ascending=[True, False]) \
        .groupby(['id', 'state']).first()
print(out)

# Output
  id         state      place     type  population
1  A       ontario     ottawa  Capital    989567.0
2  B  saskatchewan  saskatoon    Place    246376.0
```

Comment: Almost the same :p

Comment: Excellent and thank you! no way I would have thought about doing that

Answer (score 1):

You could use the fact that there are only two types and `sort_values` (ascending for "type" to have "Capital" first and descending for "population" to have the highest first):

```
(df.sort_values(by=['type', 'population'], ascending=[True, False])
   .groupby('id').first()
)
```

output:

```
            state       place      type  population
id                                                 
A        ontario      ottawa   Capital     989567.0
B   saskatchewan   saskatoon     Place     246376.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternate solution, just for fun:

```
filtered = df.loc[(df.groupby(['id', 'state'])['population'].transform('idxmax').eq(df.index) + df['type'].eq('Capital').mul(2)).groupby([df['id'], df['state']]).idxmax()]
```

Output:

```
>>> filtered
  id         state      place     type  population
1  A       ontario     ottawa  Capital    989567.0
2  B  saskatchewan  saskatoon    Place    246376.0
```